# I wonder what “listen to itself” means

Tags: meaning

several times I have seen this expression 
I could guess the meaning with the context 
 but in fact could never get the exact meaning. 
I saw it like “let the radio listening itself or BBC learn to listen to itself” 
if you need the full context, I will find it 
I am really curious what that means

edit: here is the full article

“https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/26/smarter-living/how-your-strengths-can-make-you-weaker.html?fallback=0&recId=1KR0hZKqeUZKpBcqgagoXm9qfxm&locked=1&geoContinent=AS&geoRegion=11&recAlloc=home-desks&geoCountry=KR&blockId=home-living-vi&imp_id=761797955&action=click&module=Smarter%20Living&pgtype=Homepage”

“Indeed, psychologists have found that people who consistently watch horror movies are participating in a form of exposure therapy. It might be especially useful to those of us, like my family, already predisposed toward anxiety, shrinking down the vague, existential horror of everyday life into bite-size, manageable pieces. Whether nature or nurture, “home” will always be a place where you can scare yourself to sleep.

Now, excuse me, I have a nap to take, and this serial killer podcast isn’t going to listen to itself”

this last sentence of the paragragh is where I saw the expression first. 
I found the bbc thing on the internet searching the emaning t of the expression(which attempt was fail haha)

It is really interesting that this kind of English phrase needs the context. I really didn’t know it could be neutral expression(?) 
(English is not my mother tongue, so I really have no clue with those kinds of idiomtic(?) expression)
and I love the four comments from four of you 
thanks. just reading those comments already help me

Comment: Without further context it's impossible to know exactly what was meant, unless 'the radio listening to itself' means that it has been left on when nobody is present to listen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't make sense of the idea of the *radio* listening to itself, but the idea that the *BBC* should learn to listen to itself may imply that it as an organisation or some of the broadcasters who work for it have been behaving in a hypocritical manner, broadcasting one message on air but doing something off air that contradicts the message - so it should listen to its own message and then behave accordingly.

Comment: You use *listen **to** itself* in the title of your question, yet you use *listening itself* and *listen itself* (without the *to*) in the body of your question. It would help if you could clarify the missing preposition—and also describe the context of your question in more detail. As it stands, the question doesn't make any sense—I can't imagine anybody saying anything like that. Either the exact phrasing is being misrepresented or there's more going on than has been mentioned.

Comment: If it means 'The people on program X should really take their own advice', 'Let the radio listen to itself' shows the **need** for logical agreement or rephrasing. 'The people at BBC need to take their own advice' /  'The BBC need to take their own advice'.

Answer (score 0):

*(x) + not going to + (action verb)* 
is an expression, commonly used to imply that the speaker is going to stop what they're doing at present and perform the action described:

*Excuse me, I am hungry and these vegetables aren't going to cook themselves.*

(The speaker is going to cook to sate his hunger, as the vegetables can't cook themselves)

In the podcast example, the speaker asks to be excused so they could listen to the podcast which will put them to sleep.